# How do I install ./ unpack a zImage file onto my host PC?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a zImage file of a linux kernel 2.6.32.2 that someone sent me. I dumped onto my mini2440 board and it works fine there. Now, I would like to do the same for my host PC so that I can configure the kernel using the zImage that I have, since it has a few files that were missing from my earlier kernel.
How do I go about doing this?
Thank you,
Regards

Comment: It's off-topic.Ask on www.superuser.com!

Comment: If it's a kernel that works on the mini2440 (ARM arch) then it won't run on your host machine (likely i386 or x86_64).